# ng-show and ng-hide do not fit need sometimes

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and one of the awesome things here in AngularJS are the ng-hide and ng-show directives which can be used to display certain parts of the web page or hide the. Now sometimes I don't want to show a part and it works fine then, but then sometimes it works but in an undesirable way.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p class="text-danger">{{message}}</p>
        <form name="form" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email: </label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="credentials.email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required />
                    <div ng-show="form.email.$invalid" class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-hide="form.email.$invalid" class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password: </label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="credentials.password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required ng-minlength=5 />
                    <div ng-show="form.password.$invalid" class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-hide="form.password.$invalid" class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-click="authenticate(credentials)">Login</button>
            <a href="#/register">Register</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now if the fields are valid the check symbol appears and if they are not the cross apears like so:

[image: Screenshot]

But if you look closely the addon with the cross symbol does not have rounded corners and this is probably because the addon with the check symbol is still there but hidden. Now what do I do in such situations. I would like to the div containing the check addon in such case to disappear altogether instead of staying hidden. How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ng-if="form.password.$invalid"` and `ng-if="! form.password.$invalid"` instead; that removes the element from the DOM.

Take a look at the [ngIf documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) for further research. Code snippet:

```
          <div class="input-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="credentials.password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required ng-minlength=5 />
                <div ng-if="form.password.$invalid" class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
                </div>
                <div ng-if=" ! form.password.$invalid" class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) (and a second `ngIf` with an inverted predicate) instead of [`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or `ngHide`. The former will remove elements from the DOM, while the latter will simply hide them with CSS.

From the Angular documentation:

> The `ngIf` directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to `ngIf` evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

In contrast, the `ngShow` documentation explains that it hides by adding the `.ng-hide` class:

> The `ngShow` directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the `ngShow` attribute. The element is shown or hidden by removing or adding the `.ng-hide` CSS class onto the element. The `.ng-hide` CSS class is predefined in AngularJS and sets the display style to none (using an `!important` flag).